# Can Cloud Run automatically use latest digest?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a continuous deployment pipeline setup with Github via Cloud Build Triggers. Each time a push is made to the main branch, the cloudbuild.yaml does its thing and produces a digest with a tag of `latest`. All of my digests are stored in Artifact Registry. Is there anyway to get Cloud Run to always use the digest tagged as `latest`? During the setup of my Cloud Run service this seems to be the case but after the service has been created, the image ends up resolving to a SHA value ie a specific digest rather than the tag.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by saying «to get Cloud Run to always use the digest tagged as latest»? If you mean run build -> publish «latest» artifact -> deploy the «latest» version, literally it's what you have at the moment, don't you? Whatever, adding more information like your cloud build / run configs are welcome here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you deploy a revision on Cloud Run, the LASTEST version of the image is used and cached on Cloud Run infrastructure.

If your CI/CD pipeline generate other container images, with the LATEST tag (but it's also true with defined tag), Cloud Run DOES NOT reload its cache. You have to deploy a new revision to update that cache.

Therefore, at the end of your pipeline add a cloud run deployment to update the container version.